# MySQL - How to page the results of fuzzy queries in relational queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

There are two tables in mysql.

article table:

[image: article table struct]

article_tag table

[image: article_tag table struct]

Now, I want to query the result based on the 'title of article' or the 'tag_name of article_tag', and I want to pagination the results by article_id.

here is my sql statement

```
select a.*, atag.tag_name from article a, article_tag atag 
where (a.title like '%test%' or atag.tag_name like '%test%') 
    and a.article_id=atag.article_id 
order by a.gmt_modified desc
```

But this statement querying all the results, I can't do paging according to article_id.

[image: sql result]

I don't want the stored procedure.

How should I write the sql statement?

----The following is a supplement.----

I want search the article by title or tag, so if I input 'test', I should get two articles (like the picture above), but it's just two articles, and the results amount is three because of the different tag_name, the article one(id=1) have two tag, so mysql return two datas after association query.

So there are only two data in picture above, after mybatis orm, the result class is an array [Article#1, Article#2]. And the Article#2's tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'].

I nees paging the articles, not the whole sql results

Comment: Please include a sample of the results you want.

Comment: ok. I have posted my answer below, can you check it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I think of an answer, here is my sql statement, use  `exists`

```
    SELECT
        temp.*,
        atag.*
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            a.*
        FROM
            article a
        WHERE
            a.title LIKE '%#{searchContent}%'
            OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM article_tag WHERE tag_name LIKE '%#{searchContent}%' AND a.article_id = article_id )
        ORDER BY
        a.gmt_modified DESC,
        a.gmt_create DESC
        LIMIT #{offset}, #{rows}
        ) temp
    LEFT JOIN article_tag atag ON temp.article_id = atag.article_id
```

Comment: You should not ask additional questions in the answer. This should be part of the question itself. Formulate you question and this is an evidence of your research or approach that you tried. And the question would be if it is possible to improve the query or may be there is a different better approach.

Answer (score -1):

Wait, why cant you just use order by a.article_id?
Maybe I dont understand smth..

Comment: I have supplemented my question, and posted my answer